# react bootstrap modal throwing error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Whenever I open a modal I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')" I'm not really sure what to do about it. Here's the code for the modal in question as well as the button that triggers it:

Modal:

```js
import React from 'react';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SignIn from './SignIn'
const qs = require('qs')

const auth = firebase.auth();

function Modal() {
    const account = useAuthState(auth);

    const Email = account.email;
    const [Fact, setFact] = useState('');
    const [Source, setSource] = useState('');

    const handelSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newFact = {Email, Fact, Source};
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://exampleapi.com/create',
            data: {
                "fact": {newFact}
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
          return (
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add a Fact</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="InputFact" class="form-label">Fact</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFact" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="enter your fact..." value={Fact} onChange={(e) => setFact(e.target.value)} required></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="InputSource" class="form-label">Source</label>
                                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="InputSource" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="enter your source..." value={Source} onChange={(e) => setSource(e.target.value)} required></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          )
    } else {
          // No user is signed in.
          return (
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign in</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <SignIn class="btn btn-outline-dark" message="Sign in with Google" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
    }

export default Modal
```

Button to trigger modal:

```js
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="exampleModal">
                            Submit Fact
                        </button>
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

React uses JSX instead of HTML. JSX is very similar to HTML but there are of course differences. The code you have was written as HTML (in `if(user){}` block and the `else` block)

Here's an example

```
<div className="divClass">
  <p>Hey There</p>
</div>
```

Notice the className? It has to be className instead of class because it is not HTML and you can no write HTML in React components.

And also I don't see you use react-bootstrap. You only use the class names of Bootstrap but you haven't imported the `react-bootstrap` package

For further research https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html